# VBA - Error 438 trying to automate website login

Tags: vba, http

The program is trying to identify the login area.
The problem is that in the script of the web page there is no ID to refer to so I tried to get elements by Name but it doesn't work.

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://freebitcoin.io"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
IE.document.getElementByName("email").Value = "tarnone@outlook.com"
End Sub
```

I have message  "error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: `IE.document.getElementsByName("email")(0).Value = "tarnone@outlook.com"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few elements with that class name - `form-control email`, thus the 0-th one is the one needed. And then with `.Value` the email could be set:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://freebitcoin.io"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Dim someElement As Object
    Set someElement = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("form-control email")
    someElement(0).Value = "mail@some.mail"

End Sub
```